Button that changes cell value based on an index match
absolute newbie to VBA, abit of background to the problem below.
I am expecting to receive a data set including names, order number and number of tickets.
I want to create a button that effective is a 'check in' button. When someone's name is typed in a user interface cell, it will update a cell in the row corresponding to the typed name.
Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Luke

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
